# Jquery append image src and button click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add image and button click to jquery dynamically. The image doesn't show. Below is my code.

```
$("<div/>", { id: "hide" })
    .append('<img src="/Content/Images/alert.png" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;" alt="" />')
    .append('<button runat="server" autofocus id="myButton" type="button" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;">OK</button>');
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    $("#hide").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new element in memory and appending to that but not to the DOM.

Change:

```
$("<div/>", { id: "hide" }).append...
```

To:

```
$("#hide").append...
```

Comment: I have tried your approach and it doesn't work. Maybe if I can explain what I am doing you can help me better. I need a popup image with some text to show up first thing when my page is loading. Something like a warning, users read it and click ok to dismiss and proceed. I was using session start in Global.asax which was working ok in windows server 2008 R2 but now not working in windows server 2019. I need the popup to come before the DOM loads so basically from the html header

Comment: The server shouldn't make a difference since this is client side code run in browser. You can do what you are asking using html and css

Comment: Do you have an example where to embed the html? I am using mvc5 _Layout

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got it working the way I want. I have created an html page for the redirect. I have also marked some of my controllers with

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

Then in my Glbal.asax Session_Start I check if the Session is not IsReadOnly Redirect to the html page

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.